# Can't move multiple files in a directory

Tags: c#

I am trying to move multiple files in a directory to an archive sub folder. I used a foreach loop to do the idea. Unfortunately, It can only move a file if there is only one file in the directory. But when I put multiple in the directory the Directory.move(); won't work. Can anyone help me?

```
static string antJsonSerializer(){
    #region  KDI SALES
    string[] allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\xml\"); // Put all file names in root directory into array.
    string sourceDirectory = @"C:\xml\";
    string destinationDirectory = @"C:\xml\Archive\";

    // Check if directories are existing -- Working
    bool xmlRoot = System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourceDirectory);
    if (!xmlRoot) System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(sourceDirectory);
    bool xmlArchive = System.IO.Directory.Exists(destinationDirectory);
    if (!xmlArchive) System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationDirectory);

    AntHelpers drone = new AntHelpers();

    foreach (string name in allfiles)
    {
        try
        {
            drone.xmltosql(@name.Trim());
            //File.Move(@name, destinationDirectory + (DateTime.Now.Year).ToString() + (DateTime.Now.Month).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + (DateTime.Now.Day).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + (DateTime.Now.Hour).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + ".html");  //Not working     
            Directory.Move(@name, destinationDirectory + (DateTime.Now.Year).ToString() + (DateTime.Now.Month).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + (DateTime.Now.Day).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + (DateTime.Now.Hour).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + ".html");       
            //Directory.Move(sourceDirectory, destinationDirectory); //Not working

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Main Process Catch ERR: " + e.Message);
            //ErrLogtoDB(string TRNTYPE, string extserial, string texttowrite, string logfilename)
            AntHelpers.ErrLogtoDB("SALES", @name, "Ant JSON Serializer Failed: " + e.Message, 
                "LeafCutterLogFile_JSONSerializer_" + (DateTime.Now.Year).ToString() + (DateTime.Now.Month).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + (DateTime.Now.Day).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + (DateTime.Now.Hour).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + ".html");               
        }                
        //drone.ExtractSQLSendAntHill(); //For testing: OFF 
    #endregion

    return " !!!! Work Complete !!!! ";
}
```

Comment: why are you using @name ? name should be enough

Comment: @Joshua did u put a debug and check hw many time the forloop is going on

Comment: @Joshua ur trying to save a file with year+month+day+ hour..if multiple file how can u save it with same file name..u should add second..milliseconds or something to distinguish..or else take file name with out extension then add year,month,day and hour..that is why u r not able to move multiple files at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to save a file with year + month + day + hour.html as "NAME".  If multiple files are there, then how can you save it with same file name?  Instead you should add seconds and/or milliseconds, or use something else to distinguish the file and make it a unique name.  Otherwise, take file name without the extension then add year, month, day, and hour.  That is why you are not able to move multiple files at a time, because when try to move the second file an exception will be thrown say "unable to move an existing file."

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not notice I skipped adding minute and seconds to the file name.

Comment: @JoshuaMasangcay glad to hear it helped

Answer (score 1):

Directory.Move takes a source and destination directory, not a file path. Try this:

```
Directory.Move(sourceDirectory, destinationDirectory);
```

Also, it can be run at the very end - after the foreach loop.